# UIPageView with Two UINavigationControllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

The structure of my views is first an `SWRevealViewController`. This takes in two parameters. The first parameter is a `TableViewController` that looks fine. The second parameter is the `pageViewController`. The pageViewController has two "pages", each of which is a `NavigationViewController`. The `NavigationViewControllers` will both have `TableViewControllers` as their root view.

The error I am getting is as follows: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The number of provided view controllers (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin)'

Here is my code:

(This is my app delegate)

```
MyListsViewController *myListsVC = [[MyListsViewController alloc] init];
SidebarViewController *sidebarVC = [[SidebarViewController alloc] init];
StarredTableViewController *starredListsVC = [[StarredTableViewController alloc] init];

// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] init];
//self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

//PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
//UINavigationController *myListsNav = [myListsNav initWithRootViewController:myListsVC];
UINavigationController *myListsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myListsVC];
UINavigationController *starredListsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:starredListsVC];
//NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray* viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myListsNav, starredListsNav, nil];

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.pageViewController addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.pageViewController.view addSubview:myListsNav.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.pageViewController];


//UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myListsVC];
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sidebarVC];




// UIScrollView *scrollViews
    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:self.pageViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```